# Deploy from github to bottle with reloader

Tags: python, git, github, bottle

I'm trying to get my bottle webapp to reload with the newest code, whenever it's pushed to github. It's working most of the time, but not always.

In github I've set up a trigger to http://my.server.com:8080/deploy.

In bottle I have this code for getting the latest source:

```
@post("/deploy")
def deploy():
    if request.json["ref"] != "refs/heads/master":
        return "OK"  # We only care about pushes to master

    print "deployment requested"
    call(["git", "fetch"])
    call(["git", "reset", "--hard", "origin/master"])

    print "deployment successful"
    return "OK"
```

And then later, to get the server to reload with the new source I've set the reloader:

```
run(host=host_address, port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

It often works, but sometimes an exception happens around the time the code is fetched. It seems like it fails whenever the server is busy handling other requests while it tries to reload. The stack traces I get gives me various stuff, but always something concerning a KeyboardInterrupt, which I suppose is what the reloader uses to kill the running app.

Is my strategy flawed or am I missing something about the reloader property?

Comment: Are you running the Bottle server directly? For your use case, can you use something like uWSGI, which is designed to [gracefully reload](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html) whatever app it's serving?

Comment: While that doesn't really answer my question directly I think it'll work out for me. Here is a configuration that seems to do the trick for me (notice the `py-autoreload`): 

`uwsgi --http :8080 --wsgi-file server.py --callable app --master --py-autoreload=1`